# What method(s) can be employed to solve this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $n$ in the following equation:
$$ 0 = 1780*1.006^n - 37n $$
Here's what I've tried:
$$\begin{align*}
0 &= 1780*1.006^n - 37n
\\ 37n &= 1780*1.006^n
\\ \frac{37n}{1780} &= 1.006^n
\\ n &= \log_{1.006}{(\frac{37n}{1780})}
\\ n &= \frac{\ln(\frac{37n}{1780})}{\ln(1.006)}
\end{align*}
$$
There's an $n$ inside the logarithm, which seems to be an issue. Is there a way to manipulate this equation to get an exact value of $n$?

Comment: See the first example set for Lambert W: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1

Comment: You may express the answer using [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples), but that is a special function to solve $xe^x = z$